# Doppler Cooling Limit

Tags: atomic-physics, doppler-effect

Can anyone help me understand this simple passage on Christopher Foot (Pg.189, Eq.9.24) about Doppler cooling:

$\frac{1}{2}M\frac{d\bar{v_{z}^{2}}}{dt} = (1+\eta)E_r(2R_{Scatt})-\sigma\bar{v_{z}^{2}}$

I've tried calculating the derivative both by hand and intuitively, and I can't seen to get the same result. The first term is is straightforward to me, but not the second one (it is intuitive that the result looks like the calculation of $v^2_z$, but still strange to me).